# How to detect collisions between a moving point and the stroke of an arbitrary boundary shape?

Tags: p5.js, shapes

I want to draw a circle(for example) and create a couple of points inside that circle. The points are moving randomly, but when they hit the circle's stroke, they should either stop or go inverse or react in some way (it's not that important). I know it would be easy to do with rect-like shapes, but I want to draw inside custom shapes like stars or flower.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

To find out if point inside the circle or not you just need to calculate distance from center of circle to point itself. If that distance less then radius - point inside circle.

Fun example:

```js
let c, r;
let points = [];

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  r = 50;
  c = createVector(100, 100);
  let pos = createVector(95, 110);
  let v = p5.Vector.random2D();
  points.push({p: pos, v: v});
}

function draw()
{
  background(0);
  points.forEach(point => {
    point.p.add(point.v);

    if(point.p.dist(c) > r) {
      let n = point.p.copy().sub(c).normalize();
      let d_n = point.v.dot(n);
      point.v = p5.Vector.sub(n.mult(2).mult(d_n), point.v).mult(-1);
      //pv.mult(-1);
    }
    circle(point.p.x,point.p.y,5);
  });
  
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  circle(c.x,c.y, r*2);
  
}

function mouseClicked() {
  let p = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  if (p.dist(c) < r) {
    points.push({
      p: p,
      v: p5.Vector.random2D(),
    });
  }
  // prevent default
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/v1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
click inside circle
```

Boring example:

```js
let c, radius;
function setup()
{
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  c = createVector(100, 100);
  radius = 50;
}

function draw()
{
  background(0);
  let point = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);

  let distance = c.dist(point);
  if (distance > radius) {
    fill("red"); 
  } else {
    fill("green");
  };
  circle(c.x, c.y, radius * 2);
  
  // just rendering text :)
  stroke(255);
  line(point.x,point.y, c.x,c.y);
  stroke(0);
  fill(200)
  push()
  translate(p5.Vector.add(c, p5.Vector.sub(point, c).div(2)));
  text(distance.toFixed(2),0,0)
  pop()
  
  text("Move your mouse",20,10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/v1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for circle clarification! Do you have any ideas how to do the same with a custom shape made of verteces?

Comment: @SwanPrince hi, for complex shapes you can try to implement [per-pixel collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173199/can-someone-explain-per-pixel-collision-detection) but Im not sure how useful it will be in your case. Or try to implement something more _complex_ :) You can look at [SAT - Separating Axis Theorem](https://dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/) for example